# How do I edit a character's face vertex to skim the eyeball's curvature?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I want to contour my character's face to its eyeballs. I wish I didn't have to do 1 vertex at a time as that is what I am doing now visually, I move a vertex towards the eye then I would pull back till I see it again. It's very tedious and takes a lot of editing and was wondering if there's an easier way to accomplish this.

It would be very useful if I could prevent when manipulating multiple vertex to stop moving, like a forcefield, into the eyeball. This would save me hours of work.

Example: If I have a row of vertex for the eyelid and translate them in y, they would head for the eyeball but all the vertex would stop from entering the eyeball giving the selected vertex a perfect contour against it.

In edit mode, how do I manipulate the selected vertex of the face to prevent entering into the eyeball?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the edgeloop you want to be snapped to the eyeball, turn on the face snapping function, check its "Project individual elements" option, then, using an appropriate view, press G and Enter: the vertices will snap to the eyeball.

Comment: Took a while to get what view would make it work. It was facing as in eye to eye the vertex has to be going away from the camera, any other view it just explodes into a mess.